# Firestore does not add new record when button click event used (web)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new user on Firebase Firestore. I have a collection ("vocabulary") and I want to add new document ("word", "meaning"). The code works and add new records. But when I use the same code to be executed after button click, it does not work and there is no error code. When I write Alert("test") under click function to test whether invoked or not, I see "test" message without problem. I think, it shows that the listener invoked on click. But I think add() part is not invoked. What is the possible reason?

**this code works:**

```
      database.collection("vocabulary").add({
        word:"Book",
        meaning:"xxx",
      })
      .then(function() {
        console.log("Document successfully written!");
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
      });
```

**but the same code does not work under button click:**

```
<button id="savebutton">Insert Record</button>
......

const save=document.querySelector("#savebutton");
  save.addEventListener("click",function() { 
      database.collection("vocabulary").add({
        word:"Book",
        meaning:"xxx",
      })
      .then(function() {
        console.log("Document successfully wriiten!");
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
      });
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure that your listener is invoked on click?

Comment: Your code is not checking for errors on the call to `add()`.  It returns a promise, so use `catch()` to check for errors like any other promise.  Please edit the question to show how you are doing error checking, and any error message you receive.

Comment: I've edited the explanation/code according to your comments.

Comment: How are you checking that your click event listener is even being invoked?

Comment: I've used alert("test") in the function before add() function to check whether  the click event listener is even being invoked or not. Alert message works without problem.

save.addEventListener("click",function() { 
      alert("test"); 
      database.collection("vocabulary").add({
                 ......

Comment: I've added x.preventDefault(); and it works. -> save.addEventListener("click",function(x) {x.preventDefault();......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP resolved the issue through adding the following code:

```
x.preventDefault();
```

The updated code, from what I have gathered, would seem something like this:

```
<button id="savebutton">Insert Record</button>
    ......

const save=document.querySelector("#savebutton");
  save.addEventListener("click",function(x) {
  x.preventDefault(); 
      database.collection("vocabulary").add({
        word:"Book",
        meaning:"xxx",
      })
      .then(function() {
        console.log("Document successfully wriiten!");
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
      });
    });
```

Therefore OP prevented the default action of "x", according to [public documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp#:%7E:text=The%20preventDefault()%20method%20cancels,link%20from%20following%20the%20URL), resolving the issue.